# Avoid Recursion in lag and difference operations

Tags: recursion, difference-equations

I have a panel data situation and I'm interested in taking lags and differences and using Mathematica to simplify the algebra of the result. 
Currently I'm working with a model like this:

```
y[t_] := y[t] = b[0] + b[1] x[t] + b[2] x[t - 1] + \[Eta][t]
```

which serves my needs if I want to take a `d` difference (`y[t]-y[t-d]`) or a multiple `m` of a `d` difference (`y[t]-m*y[t-d]`).

However, if I change the model slightly where `y[t]` now includes a lag of itself,

```
y[t_] := y[t] = b[0] + b[1] x[t] + b[2] x[t - 1] + b[3] y[t-1] + \[Eta][t]
```

then this no longer works. It tries to recursively plug in all the `y` lags and I get the recursion limit error. I don't want it to recursively substitute at all. I would like the output it gives me of `y[t]-y[t-1]` to contain `y[t-1]` and `y[t-1-d]`.

I'm planning on taking multiple differences, so whatever the solution I would still need to do things like `ExpandAll` and `Collect`.

I'm quite new to Mathematica, so I apologize in advance for obvious mistakes. If there are any comments on any part of my code/approach, please share them!

Comment: hey mike_s welcome! If I understand correctly you're trying to do algebraic manipulations on the structural form of `y[t]`; unless there are other considerations, using something like `y[t_]:=y[t]=...` (ie [memoization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice/8617#8617)) is probably not necessary; one way to evaluate something like eg `y[t]-m*y[t-d]` is to use [ReplaceAll](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) with [Rule](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html);

Comment: Thank you for the response! Can you give an example of how I would use ReplaceAll with Rule and then collect terms?

Comment: in order to calc `y[t] - m y[t - d]` define `yrl[t_] := b[0] + b[1] x[t] + b[2] x[t - 1] + b[3] y[t - 1] + η[t]` (instead of using `y[t_]:=...`) and then evaluate `y[t] - m y[t - d] /. y[t_] :> yrl[t]`; you should be able to collect terms in the later expression